# Python- How to generate new array formed with rows of initial 1-d array with different calculations each

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 1-d array "arr"
`arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`
and I generated a list from degree=3
`deg = list(range(1, degree+1))`

I want a matrix with shape(arr, degree)
that is from from the rows:

```
[arr^d0...] // [1,2,3,4,5]
[arr^d1...] // [1,4,9,16,25]
[arr^d2...] // [1,8,27,64,125]
```

I understand I should use a for loop but I don't know-how.

Answer (score 1):

Let numpy broadcast it for you:

```
(arr[:, None] ** deg).T
```

Output:

```
array([[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5],
       [  1,   4,   9,  16,  25],
       [  1,   8,  27,  64, 125]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
degree = 3
deg = list(range(1, degree+1))
A = np.stack([arr**i for i in deg])
print(A)
```